# SOQL error: variable does not exist

Tags: apex, soql, batch

My query looks like this:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Updated_by_Contact__c, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingCountry, BillingPostalCode, 
                                     ( SELECT Id FROM  Contacts WHERE Is_Synced__c = false ) 
                                     FROM Account 
                                     WHERE BillingStreet !=null  && BillingCity !=null && BillingState !=null && BillingCountry !=null && BillingPostalCode !=null ]);
```

So when I write this query above I'm getting an error saying

> "Variable does not exist: BillingCity, BillingState..."

However, when I end the query at:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Updated_by_Contact__c, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingCountry, BillingPostalCode, 
                                     ( SELECT Id FROM  Contacts WHERE Is_Synced__c = false ) 
                                     FROM Account 
                                     WHERE BillingStreet !=null]);
```

I'm not getting any error and it's working perfectly fine.
Could you please explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"&&" does not work in SOQL. Please replace your "&&" with "AND" keyword.